# How to use where clause inside NOT EXISTS in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to put where condition inside `NOT EXISTS` clause in sql.

In below need to check the duplicate records for that in below sql query 
i need to put Date='2012-05-07' and SecurityId= '52211'
but problem is inner join is used and i'm new bie not getting how to put these where clause
please help.

```
SELECT DISTINCT

    SecurityPriceId

FROM 
    dbo.Indicative Bond
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.BondPrice BondPrice ON 
        Indicative.SecurityId = BondPrice.SecurityId AND
        BondPrice.SecurityPriceSourceId = @SecurityPriceSourceComposite
WHERE
    Date = @Date -- Date='2012-05-07' like this
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            'z'
        FROM
            dbo.Reporting_BondPrices
    WHERE
        Reporting_BondPrices.SecurityId = BondPrice.SecurityId AND
        Reporting_BondPrices.Date = BondPrice.Date 
        --how can i put Date='2012-05-07' and SecurityId='52211'                 
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your update, I think (??) you want this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT

    BondPrice.SecurityPriceId

FROM 
    dbo.Reporting_BondIndicative Reporting_BondIndicative
    INNER JOIN 
    dbo.BondPrice BondPrice ON 
        Reporting_BondIndicative.SecurityId = BondPrice.SecurityId AND
        BondPrice.SecurityPriceSourceId = @SecurityPriceSourceComposite
WHERE
    BondPrice.Date = @Date -- BondPrice.Date='2012-05-07' like this
    AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            'z'
        FROM
            dbo.Reporting_BondPrices
    WHERE
        Reporting_BondPrices.SecurityId = BondPrice.SecurityId AND
        Reporting_BondPrices.Date = BondPrice.Date 
        --how can i put Date='2012-05-07' and SecurityId='52211'                 
        --simply put them in with and
        and Reporting_BondPrices.SecurityId='52211' and Reporting_BondPrices.Date='20120507'
    )
```

Earlier attempt at decoding your question:

<strike>You can alias your tables, like this:</strike>

```
select ...
from table as t1  --t1 will be the outer table
where not exists(select ...
                 from table as t1  --t2 will be the inner table
                 where t1.column1=t2.column1 and t1.column2<>t2.column2)
```

Comment: I just need to put those two conditions inside where how can i do this?

Comment: sql query not getting any answer are you sure that last added `and` statement is correct i want that condition in where clause but where i need to put that i dont know :(